# using async await with RESTful HTTP requests in MVC 4 with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asynchronous

**Desired result**: after user selects option to download a report via a restful call that may take a long time, a new tab opens with a message saying "please wait"  I'd like to return control back to browser so that user may click away from the "please wait" browser tab back on to the window opener browser tab and continue to browse site.   The code I've put together runs, but doesn't produce the desired result, it behaves the same way as the non-async version of my code - that is, the user's opener tab remains bound up until the call to get the download completes.  I've tried other patterns but all with the same result - no async behavior that i'd expect.   Is what I am trying to do possible, and if so, what am I not understanding?

C# code:

```
    public class ReportsController : Controller
    {
        public async Task GetDownloadAsync(string docId, string docName, string startDate, string endDate, string format)
        {
            //make request:
            HttpWebRequest GETRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myServerAddress");
            GETRequest.Method = "GET";
            GETRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            GETRequest.Accept = CreateHeader(format);

            Task<WebResponse> getResponseTask = GETRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            WebResponse GETResponse = await getResponseTask;
            (HttpWebResponse)GETRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream GETReponseStream = GETResponse.GetResponseStream();

            //retrieve response into byteArray:
            byte[] responseByteArray = convertStreamToByteArray(GETReponseStream);

            string fileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}.{2}", docName, DateTime.Now.ToString("o"), CreateFileExt(format));

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ContentType = CreateHeader(format);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", GETResponse.ContentLength.ToString());

            Response.BinaryWrite(responseByteArray);

        }
    }
```

I am calling this controller function from some javascript the cshtml view like this:

```
var win = window.open(encodeURI("GetDownloadAsync?docId=" + docId + "&docName=" + docName + "&startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate + "&format=" + reportType));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I believe I've implemented async properly, it appears that it still doesn't work.  Instead of implementing async, I was able to achieve the desired behavior by manipulating the way .Net handles Session State, decorating the controller class with:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

This provides me with the desired "async"-ish behavior, that is the effect of the tab that gets launched mapping to a controller method that makes a RESTful call to download a large file no longer blocks browsing of the rest of the site while the file is downloading.

Per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx:

> Access to ASP.NET session state is exclusive per session, which means
>   that if two different users make concurrent requests, access to each
>   separate session is granted concurrently. **However, if two concurrent
>   requests are made for the same session** (by using the same SessionID
>   value), **the first request gets exclusive access to the session
>   information. The second request executes only after the first request
>   is finished.** (The second session can also get access if the exclusive
>   lock on the information is freed because the first request exceeds the
>   lock time-out.) **If the EnableSessionState value in the @ Page
>   directive is set to ReadOnly, a request for the read-only session
>   information does not result in an exclusive lock** on the session data.
>   However, read-only requests for session data might still have to wait
>   for a lock set by a read-write request for session data to clear.